# Very weird PreparedStatement in java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I found a very odd PreparedStatement in a program today do to an error that I received.  I tracked it down and found some perplexing SQL.  Now, I am no master of SQL or PreparedStatements, but this seems very wrong.  I should also mention that this works on a coworker's computer but not mine.

```
static final String SELECT_UNCOMPLETE_TASKS_FOR_UPGRADE =
"SELECT i.employeeid, i.taskid, i.itptaskarchivecd, i.itptaskstartdt, i.itptaskcompletiondt,t.taskobsoletecd, "
+ "t.taskknowledgetx, t.taskProductid, t.taskrfrncid, t.taskcorecd, t.taskwartimecd, t.parentheaderid, "
    + "t.taskparentindcd, i.itptaskstatuscd, i.itptaskarchivedt, t.certified "
    + "FROM itptask i,task t "
    + "WHERE (i.itptaskcompletiondt is NULL "
        + "AND i.employeeid = ?1 "
        + "AND i.taskid = t.taskid "
        + "AND i.itptaskarchivecd = ?2 "
        + "AND t.taskproductcd = ?3 "
        + "AND t.taskobsoletecd = ?4 "
        + "AND t.taskcorecd = ?5) "
    + "OR (i.employeeid = ?6 "
        + "AND i.taskid = t.taskid "
        + "AND 'T' = t.taskparentindcd "
        + "AND t.taskproductcd = ?7)";
```

My question is simple, what are the numbers after the parameter placeholders (Question marks) for? If this is completely incorrect syntax, what would allow it to work in another workspace/environment?  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: what jdbc driver are you using?

Comment: what is the error u r getting?

Comment: @Pranalee: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Is your coworker using the same driver?

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, Just to make sure I used the copy from his workspace.

Comment: This is blowing my mind. How certain are you that this string is not manipulated before being passed to the `prepareStatement` method?

Comment: This looks like some kind of placeholder that would be referenced in the code later.  Are you sure this variable isn't being used/modified somewhere else in the code?  Perhaps to use as a template to create the actual statement?

Comment: @ Andreas @Siyual: I am fairly certain that this is passed directly into the connection.prepareStatement() method.  I have already left work for the day.  I will check tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @Andreas: I looked into the code this morning.  The String "SELECT_UNCOMPLETE_TASKS_FOR_UPGRADE" from my original post is used directly in the method prepareStatement().

Answer (score 5):

That particular syntax looks to be specific to JPA syntax.  In JPA, you could specify ?# to specify the parameter index via a Query object.

```
Query myQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from my_table where foo = ?1 and bar = ?2");

q.setParameter(1,myFoo);
q.setParameter(2,myBar);
```

Comment: Would this still be the case if it was used as a traditional PreparedStatement i.e.       ps = conn.prepareStatement(ITPQueryHelperSQL.SELECT_UNCOMPLETE_TASKS_FOR_UPGRADE);?

Comment: @Justin No, unless the driver specifically supports a non-standard (that is not specified by JDBC/SQL) way of identifying query parameters. JDBC **only** supports simple positional parameters (ie: `?`).